# How do I read extended annotations from Annotated?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting

[PEP 593](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/) added extended annotations via `Annotated`.

But neither the PEP nor the documentation for `Annotated` describes how we're supposed to access the underlying annotations. How are we supposed to read the extra annotations stored in the `Annotated` object?

```py
from typing import Annotated

class Foo:
    bar: Annotated[int, "save"] = 5

hints = get_type_hints(Foo, include_extras=True)
# {'bar': typing.Annotated[int, 'save']}

# Get list of data in Annotated object ???
hints["bar"].get_list_of_annotations()
```

Comment: `typing.get_args(hints['bar'])` - the same way as with any other generic object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid accessing dunder names, which are reserved by python (such access [should be avoided](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) whenever possible):

> [...] Any use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

You should use [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) helper. It is actually smarter than getting `__args__` attribute because of additional expansion step, see [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L2419) for details. It is a public API, so this should be preferred to manual dunder attribute examination.

```py
from typing import Annotated, get_type_hints, get_args

class Foo:
    bar: Annotated[int, "save"] = 5

hints = get_type_hints(Foo, include_extras=True)
annotations = get_args(hints['bar'])
print(annotations)
# (<class 'int'>, 'save')
```